# Print multiple values on a JSP page by struts property tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am trying to print the various values received from an database in action class to a JSP page by s:property tag. However it is showing only one value.

ACTION CLASS:

```
            ResultSet r = st.executeQuery("select unique(emailid) from pagequery");

            while (r.next()) {
                uniquemail=r.getString(1);
}
```

JSP PAGE:
The JSP page should show all the unique email id's. But it is showing only the first one.

```
<td>
<s:property value="uniquemail"/>
</td>
```

Comment: `while (r.next()) { uniquemail=r.getString(1);` does this seem the right way to do it for you ? You are overriding a simple variable with the new value on every iteration. Use a List or an array, and add new element to it, otherwise you will always have only the last iterated value stored. THEN use an iterator in JSP to render your collection.

Comment: Still an amateur. Can I use it like Array(Java.sql.Array)uniquemail=r.getString(1); ? I created the getters and setters above.

Comment: Use `List<String>`, or `String[]`. It's full of good examples on how to start out there, I suggest you to always lose at least some minutes before approaching new stuff to check if there is an example or a best practice or a common way to do that thing. It will save your time, your headaches and, potentially, your job :)

Comment: If you could give me the complete code as the answer would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

> ```
> while (r.next()) { 
>     uniquemail=r.getString(1);
> ```

you are overriding a single variable with the new value on every iteration. You need to use a List or an array, and add new elements to it, otherwise you will always have only the last iterated value stored.

```java
public class YourAction exteds ActionSupport{

    private List<String> mails = new ArrayList<String>();
    /* put Getter and Setter for mails here */

    public String execute(){

        /* ... other stuff here ... */    

        ResultSet r = st.executeQuery("select unique(emailid) from pagequery");
        while (r.next()) {
            mails.add(r.getString(1));
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Then use an iterator in JSP to render your collection.

```xml
Mails: 
<ul>
  <s:iterator value="mails">
    <li><s:property/></li>
  </s:iterator>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it possible to arrange them within different rows in a table?

Comment: Sure... just put <tr><td><s:property/></td></tr> instead of the <ul><li> tags

Comment: And if I want to send the value of this property to another class i.e. another Action class. It is not supporting the name attribute.

Comment: s:hidden + s:property (for sending read-only values), or s:textfield, s:textarea, s:file, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If `uniquemail` is an array you have to iterate through it like this

```
<s:iterator value="uniquemail">
    <s:property/>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: The console is showing the multiple values. However, it still does not show the multiple values.